# pre populating comments fields in facebook iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments

Can anybody let me know how can we pre populate the comments fields on Facebook from within the app.I am using Facebook SDK3.2.I can set the `pictures, captions, name` etc.But I couldnt find the `message` property for it.Can anybody let me knoew to do it?Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code to resolve the issue.

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {}];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *message = @"It is an iOS App";
NSString *urlIs = YOUR_URL;
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               kFBAppId, @"api_key",
                               message,@"message",
                               urlIs, @"link",
                               @"YOUR_IMAGE_URL", @"picture",
                               @"Name OF App", @"name",
                               @"PASS your comment here", @"description",
                               nil];

//send message to all FB IDs
NSString *path=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@/feed",@"f_userId"];
NSLog(@"fb path : %@",path);
[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:path andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: how can we create an instance of Facebook?I cannot find Facebook class  in the latest Facebook SDK 3.2.